# Problems with text Encoding

Tags: c#

I read txt file in ANSI or UTF-8 Encoding. Txt file consists of such lines:

```
79005213750:hello
79005213751:привет
79005213752:СЃРµСЂРµРіР°
```

Read it with such code:

```
TextReader readFile = new StreamReader(file_path, Encoding.Default);
foreach (string line in ReadLineFromFile(readFile))
{}

private static IEnumerable<string> ReadLineFromFile(TextReader fileReader)
{
    using (fileReader)
    {
        string currentLine;
        while ((currentLine = fileReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            yield return currentLine;
        }
    }
}
```

and after all manipulations with lines I save them:

```
SaveFileDialog saveFile1 = new SaveFileDialog();

            saveFile1.DefaultExt = "*.txt";
            saveFile1.Filter = "TXT Files|*.txt";
            saveFile1.FileName = "rus_number-pass";
            if (saveFile1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK && saveFile1.FileName.Length > 0)
            {
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(saveFile1.FileName))
                foreach (string line in digits_ru)
                {
                    file.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
```

In out I receive:

```
79005213750:hello
79005213751:РїСЂРёРІРµС‚
79005213752:РЎРѓР ВµРЎР‚Р ВµР С–Р В°
```

But expect :

```
79005213750:hello
79005213751:привет
79005213752:серега
```

Can u help me? I killed 2 days on this problem, but can't solve it=\

Comment: If you take out the manipulations, does the file save exactly the same?

Comment: Try changing the encoding on your streamwriter to UTF8 `using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(saveFile1.FileName, false, Encoding.UTF8))`

Comment: Is the editor you are using to view the file set to the correct encoding?

Comment: Romoku, received in out 79005213750:hello
79005213751:привет
79005213752:СЃРµСЂРµРіР°

Comment: @Obdgy: So, we don't know what your manipulations are, so we can't say why it's not changing line `79005213752`. But it looks like a problem there.

Comment: I guess problem is not `encoding`; problem is with your manipulation logic.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using one encoding (Encoding.Default) for Read operations and another one (UTF8) for writing.

Use different overload of System.IO.StreamWriter constructor. E.g. this one

```
public StreamWriter(string path, bool append, Encoding encoding)
```

and as the encoding parameter pass the same default encoding you pass into the Reader.

```
TextReader readFile = new StreamReader(file_path, Encoding.Default);
```

I think that after you'll see the expected characters in the output file.

Btw. be aware that using Encoding.Default is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the target encoding by using the codepage number:

```
var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
```

Which is russian, thats what you need I presume.